# Finding charge (electromagnetism course)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, mathematical-physics

I'm a maths undergrad taking a course on electromagnetism, I've drawn a diagram to represent this following question, but I'm having a bit of trouble approaching it:

"Two tiny balls of mass m = 0:1 g and charge q are suspended on silk threads of
length l = 30 cm (see picture below). Their centers are separated by D = 6 cm.
Find the charge q."

Comment: Picture? Typically you work out the sideways force from the angle the strings make to the vertical, then calculate the charge from [Coulomb's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law).

Answer (score 0):

Take one of the two balls. Then it holds that

$\sum F=0$ or equivalently

$\sum F_x=0$ and $\sum F_y=0$.

On the x axis we have the $F_c$ Coulomb's Force and $T_x$ the projection of $T$, which is the force that the silk exerts on the tiny ball. On the y axis we have the weight  $W$  of the tiny ball and $T_y$ the projection of $T$ in the $y$ axis. Hence,

$F_c=T_x$ and $W=T_y$. If we divide this relations we will get

$\displaystyle \frac{F_c}{W}=\frac{T_x}{T_y}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{F_c}{W}=tan\phi$, where $\phi$ is the angle between the axis $y$ and the silk tread.

Easily we can find this $\displaystyle tan \phi=\frac{D^2/4}{\sqrt{l^2-D^2/4}}$.

Furthermore, $W=mg$ and $\displaystyle F_c=K_c\frac{q^2}{D^2}$. So we conclude that

$\displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle K_c\frac{q^2}{D^2}}{mg}=\frac{D^2/4}{\sqrt{l^2-D^2/4}}$.

If you solve the above equation for $q$, you will get that you want.\

Hope it helps.